# Alternate to group by in realm

Tags: android, realm

I have a RealmObject class about video game info that contains multiple

```
 RealmList<RealmString> variables;
```

including developers , publishers , theme , genre etc . Now i need to group by my database according to these  realmlist variables so that i can get count of each value in RealmList and show the statistics .

Is there any efficient way to make this query ?

Here is my RealmObject class

```
public class GameDetailDatabase extends RealmObject  {
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String name;
private RealmList<RealmString> developers;
private RealmList<RealmString> franchises;
private RealmList<RealmString> genres;
private RealmList<RealmString> publishers;
private RealmList<RealmString> similarGames;
private RealmList<RealmString> themes;


public GameDetailDatabase() {
}

//setters and getters

}
```

A game can have muti developers , multi genre , multi themes so they are stored as `RealmList<RealmString>` .

Here is my RealmString class

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {

private String name;

public RealmString(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public RealmString() {
}
}
```

Now let say I have 3 game records in the database. Game A has developer as A,B and C , Game B has developer B,C,D and Game C has developer B,C . Now I want to query the data such that I get the count of the game by each developer. So in my case 
A - 1 Game 
B - 3 Game 
C - 3 game 
D - 1 game

How to do it efficiently using Realm ?

Comment: `RealmList<String>` cannot be stored that way in Realm, so I'm a bit skeptical about this question.

Comment: I am storing it as RealmList<RealmString> wher RealmString is just a wrapper class for String .

Comment: Could you post the actual class properties and an example of what you are trying to accomplish? It isn't very clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: check my edited question . Let me know if you can still not understand .

Comment: Your schema design does not allow this whatsoever. You're supposed to have a bidirectional link between actual `GameDetailDatabase` and `DeveloperDatabase` classes, then query in the form of `realm.where(DeveloperDatabase.class).findAll()`, then you can do `developer,getGames().size()` and you'd have the number of games that belongs to a given developer. Read more [here](https://hackernoon.com/realmlist-realmstring-is-an-anti-pattern-bfc10efb7ca5) and [here](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - I read your both article and it was a very good read . However i still dont understand it completely how i am going to put the data and how my model class will look . Can you give me an example in above context ?